# How do I hide the top toolbar of a Ext.Panel? (ExtJS 2.0)

Tags: extjs, toolbar

For some reason Ext.Panel.getTopToolbar() is returning an array of objects (the elements of the toolbar, but *NOT* the toolbar itself) and not an Ext.Toolbar. Because of that, I can't manage to hide an already set toolbar. How should I proceed?

Sample code:

```
function (panel)
{
    alert(panel.getTopToolbar()); // displays the list of elements in the toolbar
    panel.getTopToolbar().hide(); // error: "hide" is not a function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work, so it sounds like maybe you used `topToolbar` as a config instead of using `tbar` as the config?  If you set a `tbar` config it gets instantiated and saved as `topToolbar` which is the `Ext.Toolbar` instance exposed by `getTopToolbar()`.  If you overwrote topToolbar directly you might see this issue.

You might find this block of code in `Panel.onRender` (you'll have to include that file directly) and set a breakpoint in Firebug to see what's happening:

```
    if(this.tbar && this.topToolbar){
        if(this.topToolbar instanceof Array){
            this.topToolbar = new Ext.Toolbar(this.topToolbar);
        }
        this.topToolbar.render(this.tbar);
    }
```

Comment: Not really. I've set tbar when instantiating the Exp.Panel. You mean what's happening could be explained if panel.topToolbar was set to an array?

Comment: You need to use Firebug and figure out what panel.getTopToolbar() is actually returning.  There's no way for me to guess.  By default, your code should be working so something must be happening outside of what you posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
panel.getTopToolbar().setVisible(false);
```

Comment: You should add an explanation of why you think this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In `4.2.1` what works for me is:

```
          var topToolbar = Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
              dock: 'top',
              width: 'auto',
              id: 'mytoolbar',
              hidden: true,
              items: [...]
          });


            var p = Ext.create('App.view.MyCustomPanel', {
                html: 'test',
            });

            if (userCanSeeToolbar) {
              p.addDocked(topToolbar);
            }
```

Then dynamically I can show/hide the top toolbar:

```
 /* if (userCanSeeToolbar) { */
 p.getDockedComponent('mytoolbar').show();
 p.getDockedComponent('mytoolbar').hide();
```